# Varying space between table view cell and footer title

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios9

I have a very basic grouped `UITableViewController` with `UITableViewCellStyleDefault` cells with just the `textLabel.text` set.

Usual suspect methods: `numberOfSectionsInTableView`, `numberOfRowsInSection`, `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

Only 'fancy' thing I have is `titleForFooterInSection` which just returns `NSStrings` of varying length.

I just noticed that the space between a cell and the footer text is proportional to the number of lines in the footer text.  It's not a little bit either: on the iPhone 6 plus screenshot if ranges from 52 (2 line footer) to 95 (8 line footer) pixels.

This looks crappy. Does anyone know if this is a 'feature'? Is there an easy way to correct this (other than creating my own footer views)?

Running iOS 9.3.2.

Same thing happens in Apple's own apps, for example Settings > Control Centre.

Answer (score 0):

Please implement heightForFooterViewInSection method of UITableView.

Comment: That would be rather hacky and difficult because I'd need to capture the exact font and width available with iOS uses. Also I'd get these same strings twice. Question: Are you sure this will not just cut of the bottom part of the footer? I'll try out of curiosity.